# Grails + Mongo: GORM mysteriously thinks a object referenced by an embedded field has a changed propery

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have a domain class called `Form` which has an embedded field called `union` of type `Organization` which is embedded. `Organization` has the field `createdByUser`. User has a field `organization` of type `Organization` added by AST transformation.

So, whenever i try to save a `Form` object, it tries to change the user reference by `createdByUser` to an organization id of `1` for mysterious reasons.

Comment: what fields of Form are you modifying before calling save on it?  what is changing? createdByUser's organiztion id is becoming 1?

Comment: @DegenSharew it's the first save.

Comment: How about explicitly setting the organization reference on the createdByUser field before you save, instead of letting it decide!?

Comment: @clife the thing is I don't care about the `createdByUser`. That field was populated when the `organization` was created. Why would GORM think it was changed anyway?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense to me, maybe clarifying it with a code example or upload a sample to github that reproduces the issue would provide some clarity

Comment: @GraemeRocher you're right! I was a bit hard for me write the question as it touches a lot of code. I'll try doing what you said and get back to you..