# How to intercept and log mongodb queries?

Tags: mongodb, grails, gmongo

How do I get the exact query sent from `gmongo` driver to `mongod` (for debugging purposes).

In ***mysql*** it is achieved by adding `logSql = true` to datasource.

I am writing an aggregate query with a matching pipeline between a start and end date. The dates are given as normal java Date classes.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
            [
                $match:
                    [
                        dateIssued: [

                            $gte: fromDate,

                            $lte: toDate
                        ]
                    ]
            ], 
            [
                $group:
                    [
                        _id: "\$type", 
                        total: 
                            [
                                $sum: 1
                            ]
                    ]
            ])
```

And it doesn't seem to filter the results based on the date. It's giving me back everything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this from the driver, I found the best way to do it is use `mongosniff`. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongosniff/

Comment: Graeme, not sure if this is the right place to notify you but we've been unable to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714307/grails-mongo-gorm-mysteriously-thinks-a-object-referenced-by-an-embedded-fiel. We've tried stepping through what mongodb plugin tries to to do to no avail. I hope you will take a few secs to look at my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the exact query sent from gmongo driver to mongod (for debugging purposes)?

Turn on mongodb [profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/profile/) and you can [log all your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204341/mongodb-logging-all-queries).

> In mysql it is achieved by adding logSql = true to datasource.

I think you want this to automatically happen based on your configuration in Grails. Then, do the following:

In `Config.groovy`:

```
mongo.profiling.enabled = true
```

In `Bootstrap.groovy`:

```
GMongo mongo = new GMongo(grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.host, grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.port)
DB db = mongo.getDB(grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.databaseName)

if( grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.username ) {
    boolean auth = db.authenticate(grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.username ,
            grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.password ? grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.password.toCharArray() : "" )

    if( !auth ) {
        log.error( "MongoDB failed to authenticate")
        return
    }
}

if( grailsApplication.config.mongo.profiling.enabled ) {
    db.setProfilingLevel(2)

}
else {
    db.setProfilingLevel(0)
}
```